# Modifying behavior of yAxys component with media queries

Tags: javascript, charts, media-queries, responsive, echarts

I am creating a responsive chart with ECharts, and as a way to improve the user's visual experience I need to remove the intermediate values ​​between the `0` (min value) and `1` (max value) displayed on the yAxis:

[image]

This is my code:

```
media: [{
    query: {
      maxWidth: 500
    },
    option: {
      title: {
        textStyle: {
          fontSize: 10
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        nameGap: 25,
      },
      xAxis: {
        nameGap: 19
      },
      legend: {
        right: 0,
        top: '15%',
        orient: 'vertical'
      },
    }
  }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try playing around with the [`yAxis.interval`](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#yAxis.interval) option.

---

**Clean solution**

```
option: {
    yAxis: {
        interval: 1
    }
}
```

or use a function (closure):

```
option: {
    yAxis: {
        interval: (() => {
            return 1;
        })()
    }
}
```

It accepts both a number and a function, so you can achieve what you want, even with variable datasets.

---

**Dirty solution**

```
option: {
    yAxis: {
        interval: 9999999999
    }
}
```

Since eCharts *always* shows the `min` and `max` value on the yAxis, setting the interval very high removes all the numbers in between.